# Stored Procedure that has table argument in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, procedure, table-variable

### Table Argument as OUTPUT

I want to pass a table variable into a procedure that has table argument as output,
but not as read only! I want to be able to modify that argument inside the PROC.
Is this possible?
If it's not possible, is there another way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to copy the table valued parameter into a table variable or temp table

```
CREATE PROC DoStuff
    @tvp SomeTableType READONLY
AS
..
SELECT * INTO #LocalCopy FROM @tvp; -- take local copy
...
DoStuff -- do processing on the input
...
SELECT ... FROM LocalCopy;  --return results to client
GO
```

After comment, a table valued parameter can not be declared OUTPUT. From [CREATE PROC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)

> A table-value data type cannot be specified as an OUTPUT parameter of a procedure.

Comment: @BlackViking: updated. Your table parameter can not be OUTPUT.