# define table argument as OUTPUT in PROC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, procedure, table-variable

### define table argument as OUTPUT in PROC

how can i define table argument as OUTPUT in PROC and don't READONLY?
if it's not possible, is there another way to do same this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_MySP
    @TVP CustomTableType READONLY
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

   --Your Code
   Select * From @TVP


Go
```

Also, if you want to do modification to Table Value Parameter, then:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_MySP
    @TVP CustomTableType READONLY
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM @TVP; -- copy
    --Your Code (processing)
    SELECT * FROM #tempTable;  --result
GO
```

Comment: Same as my answer on the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851391/stored-procedure-that-has-table-argument-in-t-sql

Comment: @gbn Ok got it...It seems duplicate.

Comment: thank you very much!but i means that i want to define TVP as OUT Argument for example define int out parameter
CREATE PROC usp_MySP
@i INT OUT
AS
...